# Cannot call generic std::function member from template class

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, c++11

When compiling the following code:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename functionSignature>
class Class
{        
    std::function<functionSignature> func;
public:
    Class(const std::function<functionSignature>& arg) : func(arg) {}
    void callFunc() { func(); }
};

void f(const int i) {}

int main()
{
    Class<void(const int)> a(std::bind(f, 10));
    a.callFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

The VS 2015 compiler generates the following error message at the sixth line:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.
```

Now, I believe this is because the compiler thinks `functionSignature` is not, well, a function signature; the same error happens when I instantiate and try to call `operator()` on an `std::function<int>` instead of `std::function<int()>`, for instance.

How can I guarantee that the template argument will always be a function signature, so that I can call `operator()` on the `std::function`?

Comment: Can you please update your code exactly how you are calling your class and how you initialize your class?

Comment: Yes, an actual MCVE would help. Just add a toy `main` that creates an instance of your `Class<some stuff here>` then does `.callFunc()` on it, and confirm it compiles & generates the error in MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

> ```
> Class<void(const int)> a(std::bind(f, 10));
> ```

The function `Class::callFunc()` invokes `func()` -- i.e., no arguments. The result of `std::bind(f, 10)` is also a function that takes no arguments, which is consistent with the template argument to the class template. Using `Class<void(const int)>` is inconsistent with both the usage in the class template and the initialization.

The solution is easy: Change the errant line to

```
Class<void()> a(std::bind(f, 10));
```

Comment: Well, since the OP changed the original question, my first answer still makes sense, but this one is more focused indeed.

Comment: @skypjack - There wasn't much to go on at the time you wrote your answer. You read the OP's mind, and then some. +1, on your answer, that is.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you want something like that:

```
template <typename F>
class Class;

template<typename R, typename... P>
class Class<R(P...)> {
public:
    std::function<R(P...)> func;
    void callFunc(P... p) { func(p...); }
};
```

By using partial specialization that way you can easily define the type you want.
As an example, you can use it as:

```
Class<int(double)> c;
```

Of course, I noticed that you have no constructors for your class, so to invoke `func` is not a good idea, but it's quite easy to define it and pass a proper function as an argument.

It follows a complete and working example where I've used the `operator()` to invoke the function:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename F>
class Class;

template<typename R, typename... P>
class Class<R(P...)> {
public:
    Class(std::function<R(P...)> f): func{f} { }
    void operator()(P... p) { func(p...); }
private:
    std::function<R(P...)> func;
};

void fn() { }

int main() {
    std::function<void()> f = fn;
    Class<void()> c{f};
    c();
}
```

Comment: +1, This answered the question I googled for and the one I thought this was about based on the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

http://ideone.com/fork/IZ0Z1A

If functionSignature is NOT a function, std::function will throw errors when you create Class but you could add a constructor and throw there a `static_assert(std::is_function<functionSignature>::value == true," ");`if you want I guess.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename functionSignature>
class Class
{
public:
    std::function<functionSignature> func;
    void callFunc() { func(); }
};

void f()
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Class<decltype(f)> t {f};
    t.callFunc();

    return 0;
}
```